# How to pull data for and display an Association as a multiple-select checkbox in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm setting up a user access model with Roles in a separate table, and linked to Users by a UserRoles table.

I currently have the following in Model/Table/UsersTable.php:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Roles', [
    'through' => 'UserRoles'
]);
```

and the following in Model/Table/RolesTable.php:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'through' => 'UserRoles'
]);
```

and the following in Model/Table/UserRolesTable.php:

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Roles', [
    'foreignKey' => 'role_id'
]);
```

I have 3 different roles created, 'viewer', 'creator', and 'administrator'. I've successfully set privileges based on user types. Where I am getting stuck is adding roles to a user via an association form.

Right now I have given Administrator users the ability to edit user information. This works for basic information that I have in the Users table, but I can't figure out how to set up the form field for the associated Role. I would like it to be a checkbox where the Administrator can select each privilege for the user.

I'm currently doing this, which is not giving me what I want:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('Users.role', ['type' => 'checkbox']);
```

This is giving me a single checkbox with the label "Role". I want to pull each row from my Roles table and list them all as options.

I have a few questions relating to this:

1) This seems really elementary but I'm just not finding it clearly stated. What code do I need in my UsersController to pull the list of all Roles? (not just those associated with the current User, but all objects in the Roles table.)

2) What form input code do I need to display checkboxes with all possible Roles, and show the current user privileges (in my UserRoles table) as already checked off? I think I need something like this in my form:

```
 echo $this->Form->select('User.Role', $options, ['multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

...but I can't tell what $options should be, and how to set already-selected values.

I am currently pulling Roles with my User object to be edited:

```
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Roles'],
        'Users.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ]);
```

...but I'm having trouble converting it into a checkbox form selection.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a list of checkbox out of some options, you first need to send the options from the controller:

```
$this->set('roles', $this->Users->Roles->find('list'));
```

Then, in your template add a `multiple => checkbox` input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('roles', ['multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $roles]);
```

It is not necessary to prefix your input names with `User.` just name your inputs as the properties of a User entity.

Comment: is there a way to set whether each value is checked using the $this->Form->input syntax? for example if I have an array of $selectedRoles that I'm testing in_array for?

Comment: When you do `$user->get($id, ['contain' => ['Roles']])` and pass `$user` to `$this->Form->create($user)` It will automatically know what roles where previously selected. So you don't need to do anything extra there